# resume parsing using stanford-nlp

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to make a resume parsing application using stanford-nlp. I read in stanford-nlp customer reads , that stanford-nlp can be used to make a resume parsing application.

What approach should I use to go a head. I tried using Stanford Named Entity Recognizer. It showed all the names in resume but failed at many times in geting surnames.

How can I get skills and experience from the resumes

Comment: I think this is a bit too open ended to have a simple answer. Stanford CoreNLP will extract named entities, extract custom named entities from a list of regular expressions (see TokensRegexNERAnnotator) and can do potentially useful things like dependency parsing (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml) or shallow relation extraction (e.g., http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml). But it is primarily a useful tool for your problem, rather than an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: @GaborAngeli Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Stanford NER only retrieves persons, locations and organizations. In order to retrieve skills you should read other methods or re-train the NER. You can use stackoverflow [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) as a starting point.